# Style z-index does not work

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

In my application I have features that are added to the layer in this order:

```
feature_1
feature_2
feature_3
```

However I want their z-order be reverse, so that feature_1 will overlap other features. I thought `zIndex` property of Style should help, but it does not. I set it like so:

```
feature_1.setStyle(
    new ol.style.Style({
        ...
        zIndex: 999999
    })
);

feature_2.setStyle(
    new ol.style.Style({
        ...
        zIndex: 111
    })
);

feature_3.setStyle(
    new ol.style.Style({
        ...
        zIndex: 0
    })
);
```

And it does not help. Feature_3 still overlaps other features.

Comment: No, he doesn't, however he can change ordering with display:flex

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/layer-z-index.html), if you can use several layers.

Comment: i have the same issue... have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For the `z-index` to take effect, an element must be positioned (i.e. not the default of `static`).

Ex: `position:relative`

Comment: Is it a feature property?

Comment: I checked documentation, default feature parameters and default feature prototype and see nothing about position. So, if you do not decypher what you mean by "element", I could not accept your answer.

Comment: So, would you be so kind to provide a teeny-weeny example?

Comment: Whatever elements you're applying the z-index to must have their position property set to something other than static.

Comment: So, a feature defined like `new ol.Feature({ ... })` can also be considered an "element". And doing this like `new ol.Feature({position:"relative",...})` should work?

Comment: I'm not familiar with openlayers, just CSS :)

Comment: Then your answer has nothing to do with OpenLayers :)

Comment: Not strictly, however the issue with the z-index not being applied should still hold true.

Comment: Absolutely out of context. Z-index in OpenLayers has nothing to do with DOM elements.

Comment: @JonatasWalker - so you're saying that the z-index here is not CSS related?

Comment: Exactly, completely unrelated. See [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/layer-z-index.html).